# Android onBackPressed issue

Tags: android, webview, onbackpressed

I created a basic webview app following instructions from web.
everything works well except the backpress button, when webview connected to server backpress goes to home screen, but when i clicked the home in menu items (search and aboutpage) the app closed.
Here is my code

MainActivity.java

```
package com.dijitalyayincim.cekmekoy.cekmekoy_web;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView webView;
    private boolean isRedirected;



    private ProgressBar progress;

    String url = "file:///android_asset/www/index.html";
    String url1 ="http://www.cekmekoy.info/index.php?option=com_sppagebuilder&view=page&id=12";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //setContentView(R.layout.aa);



       webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        startWebView(webView, url);

    }

    @Override
     public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                finish();
                return true;

            case R.id.action_info:
                Element adsElement = new Element();
                adsElement.setTitle("Advertise with us");

                View aboutPage = new AboutPage(this)
                        .isRTL(false)
                        .setImage(R.drawable.logo_cekmekoy)
                        .addItem(new Element().setTitle("Version 1.0"))
                        .addItem(adsElement)
                        .addGroup("Bize Ulaşın")
                        .addEmail("info@cekmekoy.info")
                        .addWebsite("http://www.cekmekoy.info/")
                        .addFacebook("cekmekoyinfo")
                        .addTwitter("cekmekoyinfo")
                        .addYoutube("UCYt3Z595jctz5oUhg0SMLqQ")
                        .addInstagram("cekmekoy_info")
                        .create();

                        setContentView(aboutPage);
                setTitle("Bize Ulaşın");
                        return true;


            case R.id.action_search:

                setContentView(R.layout.test);
              webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.search);
               startWebView(webView, url1);
                setTitle("Arama");



            default:
                // If we got here, the user's action was not recognized.
                // Invoke the superclass to handle it.
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
    private void startWebView(WebView webView,String url) {

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            ProgressDialog progressDialog;


            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                if (url.startsWith("tel:")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(url));
                    startActivity(intent);
                    view.reload();
                    return true;
                }
                view.loadUrl(url);
                isRedirected = true;
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                isRedirected = false;
            }

            public void onLoadResource (WebView view, String url) {
                if (!isRedirected) {
                    if (progressDialog == null) {
                        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                        progressDialog.setMessage("Yükleniyor...");
                        progressDialog.show();
                    }
                }

            }
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                MainActivity.this.setTitle(view.getTitle());
                try{
                    isRedirected=true;

                    if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        progressDialog = null;
                    }



                }catch(Exception exception){
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        });

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl(url);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

i really appreciate if you can help

thanks...

Comment: So, What do you want ? Do post clearly.

Comment: This is correct what is happening because on search or info action you are setting a new content to activity layout and that is related to web view, which is having the first page only which is not able to go back to the home page. So it will happen on the back press as per your code. Check by doing one more action on searched or info web view page by opening one more page and then do back press.

Comment: Sorry, when i backpress on aboutpage (menuitem) and search page(menuitem) i want it to go to the home page and then if backpressed again, exit

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
                    mWebView.goBack();
                } else {
                    finish();
                }
                return true;
        }

    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Use this code. Hope help you.

Answer (score 0):

Comment this finish line.and use your method.   webView.goBack();

```
  @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
 //                finish();
            return true;
 }
}
```